# Target specific gear with Openshift scalable PHP application

Tags: php, caching, openshift, haproxy

I have a scalable PHP application deployed on Openshift. The app is available at two different URLs, one for the front end, and the other for the REST API that it exposes.

I know Openshift provides by default a way for subsequent requests coming from a user to be "stuck" to one gear (sticky session) but I was wondering if there is a way to force the same behaviour on the second host?

I tried forcing the GEAR cookie for the second host but it does not seem to be working...

I'm trying to achieve this for caching purposes (some of the models that are used to render the front end are also used on the API and I would love it if those were already cached).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the setup of your application?

Comment: First of all thanks for looking into this. In the meantime I figured out a different way to get past the issue I was primarily trying to solve through the sticky sessions so the above is no longer required.